# Convertir elemento dinamico en clickeable

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, click

Tengo el siguiente elemento en mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo individual de cada caja**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box bg-aqua">
            <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></span>

            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Caja</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">41,410</span>

              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div>
              </div>
                  <span class="progress-description">
                    70% Increase in 30 Days
                  </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.info-box-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.info-box -->
        </div>
```

La cuestión es que la muestro dependiendo del numero de caja, puede se 1 o 1000, la cuestion es que quiero volver el elemento clickeable como un `<a href="">` pero que no me dirija a ninguna pagina sino que me haga una accion como esta DEPENDIENDO que caja clickee:

```
$(".caja1").click(function() {
    console.log("Clickeo la caja # X");
});
```

Como puedo volver clickeable el elemento y al mismo tiempo en javascript saber que elemento clickee?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**EDITADO**

Codigo actualizado a la respuestas pero no lanza nada (Afecte que las este mostrando dinamicamente en el funcionamiento del `.click()...`?)

```
$("#buscarLote").click(function() {

    var valor = document.getElementById("loteBuscar").value;
    var totalCajas;
    var iter = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OIT.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: { funcion: "funcion6", box: valor },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            totalCajas = respuesta.cantidadCajas;
            //console.log(respuesta.cantidadCajas);
            for (var i = totalCajas; i > 0; i--) {
                $(".contenedorCajas").append('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cajas" id="' + (i - 1) + '"><div class="info-box bg-aqua"><span class="info-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i></span><div class="info-box-content"><span class="info-box-text">Caja ' + (i - 1) + '</span><span class="info-box-number">41,410</span><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div></div><span class="progress-description">70% Increase in 30 Days</span></div><!-- /.info-box-content --></div><!-- /.info-box --></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});

$(".cajas").click(function() {
    console.log($(this.id));
});
```

Comment: Puede tener una clase general para todas las cajas y escuchar el evento para esa clase. `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 caja">`  y en JQuery escucharía el evento a esa clase `$(".caja").click(...)`  ,¿Qué datos desea obtener de la caja o hacer con la caja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede crear una clase general para toda las cajas y escuchar el evento a dicha clase. Luego que se da el evento si por ejemplo deseamos el titulo de la caja utilizamos `find` para encontrar la clase `.info-box-text` lo mismo funcionaría para otra clase que esté dentro de la caja  como `.info-box-number`

Como añade los elementos en el DOM , tiene que asignar el `listener` a un elemento que si exista en el DOM, como es el caso de `document`. `$(document).on('click','.caja',function() { ... }`

```js
$(document).on('click','.caja',function() {
    //$(this) hace referencia al div con la clase caja que se clickeo
    console.log($(this).find('.info-box-text').text());
    console.log($(this).find('.info-box-number').text());
    //Si desea obtener el id
    console.log("ID " + this.id);
    // Puede agrear más funcionalidad o acción a realizar
});
```

```css
.caja{
  background : #ccc;
  margin :2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 caja"  id="caja1">
  <div class="info-box bg-aqua">
    <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></span>

    <div class="info-box-content">
      <span class="info-box-text">Caja 1</span>
      <span class="info-box-number">41,410</span>

      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div>
      </div>
          <span class="progress-description">
            70% Increase in 30 Days
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 caja" id="caja2">
  <div class="info-box bg-aqua">
    <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></span>

    <div class="info-box-content">
      <span class="info-box-text">Caja 2</span>
      <span class="info-box-number">42,110</span>

      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div>
      </div>
          <span class="progress-description">
            70% Increase in 30 Days
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> En mi ejemplo uso la clase caja en singular. debería modificar esto ya
>   que en su pregunta editada usa `cajas`

Comment: Gracias, el ejemplo es correcto, pero a la hora de utilizarlo aunque este bien no funciona, edite la pregunta para mostrar como muestro las cajas.

Comment: @Baker1562 actualicé mi respuesta. cambiando el `$('.caja).click(..)` por  `$(document).on('click','.caja',function() { ...}`

Comment: Ahora si funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Baker1562 perfecto .Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Podrías agregar una clase a cada una de tus cajas y, mediante la palabra reservada `this`, obtener por ejemplo el id de cada caja.

La palabra reservada `this` hace referencia al elemento con el cual se está interactuando en cada momento.

#### Obtener valor cuando generas los elementos dinámicamente - Eventos delegate

Como estás agregando los elementos dinámicamente mediante la función `.append()` de JQuery necesitarás utilizar un evento delegate, el cual puedes generar mediante la función **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** de JQuery.

Te voy a indicar varias frases sacadas de la propia documentación de JQuery:

> **Los controladores de eventos están vinculados solo a los elementos seleccionados actualmente; deben existir en el momento en el que tu código hace la llamada a .on()**.

Es decir, si hiciéramos la llamada al método `.on()` de JQuery como de costumbre (directamente a la clase `.caja`), tendríamos que agregar todos los elementos mediante la función `.append()` antes de llamar al método `.on()`.

Ejemplo realizando la llamada al método `.on()` después de agregar los elementos:

```js
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja1' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja2' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja3' class='caja'></div>");

$(".caja").on('click', function(){
  console.log("Clickeo la caja: " + this.id);
});
```

```css
.caja{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cajas"></div>
```

Ejemplo realizando la llamada al método `.on()` antes de agregar los elementos:

```js
$(".caja").on('click', function(){
  console.log("Clickeo la caja: " + this.id);
});

$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja1' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja2' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja3' class='caja'></div>");
```

```css
.caja{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cajas"></div>
```

Como puedes observar, en este segundo ejemplo, tal y como mencionaba la documentación, el evento no puede ser lanzado cuando los elementos se agregan después de haber realizado la llamada del método `.on()`.

Para ello, será necesario que utilices los **eventos delegate**. Según la documentación:

> **Los eventos delegate tienen la ventaja de que pueden procesar eventos de elementos descendientes que son añadidos al documento más tarde**.

Es decir, podemos agregar un controlador de eventos al elemento padre pero que a su vez, va a procesar un evento en caso de que hayamos agregado un elemento descendiente a él.

Para crear un evento delegate la estructura sería así:

```
$(referencia a elemento padre).on('click', referencia a elemento hijo, function(){
    //Código aquí
});
```

Podríamos hacer referencia a `document` como elemento padre pero yo he preferido agregarle un contenedor a las cajas ya que de esta manera, en caso de que tuvieras otros elementos con la clase `.caja` fuera de este contenedor y no quisieras agregarles dicho evento, no se les aplicaría.

Te dejo un ejemplo aplicando todo lo anterior:

```js
$("#cajas").on('click', '.caja', function(){
  console.log("Clickeo la caja: " + this.id);
});

$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja1' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja2' class='caja'></div>");
$("#cajas").append("<div id='caja3' class='caja'></div>");
```

```css
.caja{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cajas"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, el ejemplo es correcto, pero por alguna razón extraña el console.log no lanza nada. (Afecta que este mostrando las cajas desde un .append() en el javascript dinamicamente?)

Comment: Exactamente, con elementos que son agregados dinámicamente debes hacer uso de la función `on()` de la siguiente manera: `$(".caja").on('click', function(){
  console.log("Clickeo la caja: " + this.id);
});` Ya que la función `click()` solo sirve para elementos previamente cargados en el DOM

Comment: @Baker1562 Te he agregado una explicación de como realizar el proceso de escuchar eventos usando la función `.append()`. Espero que ahora te quede más claro :)

Comment: @Genarito Totalmente de acuerdo. He agregado una explicación de cómo solucionarlo mediante los `event delegate`.